# How do I make that different button, different imageview will be affected

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm very new to this coding thing and I hope that anyone of you can help me out on this. Basically I have three different buttons with different image view and I would like to upload them to my MySQL. However when I press all three button at different times, it will only affect the 1 of the image views. Appreciate if you could help.

```
    public static final int resultloadimage = 1;
    private static final int RESULT_OK = -1;

    Button btnupadloadnric, btnuploaddl, btnuploadvl,updateButton;
    ImageView ivnric,ivdl,ivvl;
    EditText fullanme, telephone;
    String encodedimage;
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    String filename = null;
    byte[] image = null;
    private byte[] byteArray;


    public Profile() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        btnupadloadnric = v.findViewById(R.id.btnAdminUploadNRICFragment);
        btnuploaddl = v.findViewById(R.id.btnAdminUploadDLFragment);
        btnuploadvl = v.findViewById(R.id.btnAdminUploadVCLFragment);
        ivdl = v.findViewById(R.id.ivadminprofiledl);
        ivnric = v.findViewById(R.id.ivadminprofilenric);
        ivvl = v.findViewById(R.id.ivadminprofilevl);
        fullanme = v.findViewById(R.id.etAdminFullNameProfileFragment);
        telephone = v.findViewById(R.id.etAdminPhoneNumberProfileFragment);
        updateButton = v.findViewById(R.id.btnAdminUpdateProfileFragment);
        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();


        btnuploadvl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, resultloadimage);
            }
        });
        btnuploaddl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, resultloadimage);
            }
        });
        btnupadloadnric.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, resultloadimage);

            }
        });
        updateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                UploadImage uploadImage = new UploadImage();
                uploadImage.execute("");
            }


        });

    return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultcode,data);
        if (requestCode == resultloadimage && resultcode == RESULT_OK && null !=data){
            Bitmap originbitmap = null;
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            InputStream imagestream;
            try {
                imagestream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                originbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imagestream);


            }catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (originbitmap!=null){
                this.ivdl.setImageBitmap(originbitmap);
                Log.w("Image in", "Done");
                try {
                    Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable)ivdl.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90 , byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                    encodedimage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);
                    UploadImage uploadImage = new UploadImage();
                    uploadImage.execute("");

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.w("asd", "Exception");
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
        else{
System.out.println("Error Occured");
        }

    }


    public class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con==null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Check Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    String command = "Insert into driverprofile (DrivingL, Username, Password) values('" + encodedimage + "', 'Admin1', '12345')";
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(command);
                    if (rs.next()){}
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.getMessage();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change request codes for each gallery intent on each button click.

```
btnuploadvl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, "request code for btnuploadvl");
        }
    });
    btnuploaddl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, "request code for btnuploaddl");
        }
    });
    btnupadloadnric.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, "request code for btnupadloadnric");

        }
    });
```

And then check request code detecting which button is clicked on `onActivityResult`.

Comment: hey faranjit, thanks for getting back to me. I actually tried that but it doesn't work still.